# how can I protect xml files used by my vb winform app?

Tags: vb.net, dll

I am aware that xml files are text files that cannot be password protected, but I am looking for a way to protect a bunch of xml files from being easily viewed. They are needed though for my winform application.  Can I package them into a .lib or .dll? If so, how do I read from them if in a dll? Sorry, quite new to programming. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can embed any file into your assembly

1. goto to the Project Properties
2. there is a tab called "Resources"
3. in the Toolbar open the drop Down "Add Resource" and select "Add Existing File"

You can access your resource in your code with:

```
My.Resources.MyNewResource
```

Answer (score 2):

It deepens on how far your want to go.  You could just serialize your XML to binary, that would most likely stop 99% of nosy people.  To take it a step further you could also Encrypt your XML.

[How to encrypt and decrypt a file by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010)